# How to extract anonymous callback which closes over some variable?

Tags: javascript, callback

I have a function which uses Array.prototype.forEach and passes a callback to it. I'd like to extract that callback into a separate function so I can test it. The problem is that callback uses a parameter from outer function and the signature of callback is, of course, determined by Array.prototype.forEach and I can't change it. Is there any way at all I can extract this callback? Code sample is below:

```
var enableMarks = function (arrEvents, arrGeneratedEvents) {
  var marksLength = arrEvents[0].marks().length;
  var generatedMark;
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < arrGeneratedEvents.length; i++) {
    programEvents.forEach(function (programEvent) {
      if (programEvent.pairOrderToShow === arrGeneratedEvents[i]) {
        generatedMark = generateNumber(0, marksLength - 1);
      }
      //some other code here, not important for question
    });
  }
```

};

So, my callback uses arrGeneratedEvents from outer function and I don't know if it's possible to somehow pass this to extracted callback.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this way

```
var enableMarks = function(arrEvents, arrGeneratedEvents) {
  var marksLength = arrEvents[0].marks().length;
  var generatedMark;
  var i;
  // this is the callback function of forEach
  // beise element, it can also acceopt the index and the to traverse array
  function testFun(item) {
      if (programEvent.pairOrderToShow === arrGeneratedEvents[i]) {
        generatedMark = generateNumber(0, marksLength - 1);
      }
      //some other code here, not important for question
    }

  for (i = 0; i < arrGeneratedEvents.length; i++) {
    //calling the callback function here, & passing an argument
    programEvents.forEach(testFun);
  }
};
```

Comment: I'm not sure that will work.  `testFun(elem to pass)` doesn't evaluate to a function type (and `forEach` expects a function type).

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I was refering to the first example given here

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: I don't see any example there that doesn't pass a function type to `forEach` ;)

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth, I got your point, sorry it was mistake from my side , I could not understand it. Have edited the answer. Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 1):

```
let cbfunc = function (programEvent, index, arrGeneratedEvents,i) {
  if (programEvent.pairOrderToShow === arrGeneratedEvents[i]) {
    generatedMark = generateNumber(0, marksLength - 1);
  }
  //some other code here, not important for question
};

programEvents.forEach(cbfunc);
```

now you call cbfunc as a function from anywhere in your code.